# Why this don't work javaFX Oracle example

Tags: image, javafx

This is example on site `Oracle`  and they say this working.

```
     // load the image
     Image image = new Image("file_name.png");

     // simple displays ImageView the image as is
     ImageView iv1 = new ImageView();
     iv1.setImage(image);
```

On site is picture result code. But it did not work for me. I see exception

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Invalid URL or resource not found.

Comment: Looks like you didn't specify the correct url for `file_name.png`. Better use `Class.getResource` (for resources) or `File.toURI().toURL()` or `Path.toUri().toURL()` (local files) and get a string representation from the url returned using `.toExternalForm()`

Comment: @fabin Thanks to the excellent response, so sorry, what Oracle don't correct write this code..

Answer (score 0):

Probably outdated. Try this.

```
File selectedFile = new File("yourfile.png");
String filePath = selectedFile.getAbsolutePath();
Image image = new Image(selectedFile.toURI().toURL().toString());
ImageView iv1 = new ImageView();
iv1.setImage(image);
```